# Dependency Analysis Code Error / CodeSign error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm going to get this out of my system before continuing so that you can see my dilema.
I HATE MacOSX, iOS, and apple in general.

The little iPhone 4S I was using to program was having little bit of troubles because if was timing out all the time on the company's wifi, and it was taking more than halve of my time being able to even debug.
So now I was given an iPad mini from a coworker, with the new and shiny lightning connector. I connect it to the machine, I tell the os that I will use it to develop, give it the company developer account, and all seems fine... until I try to build

CodeSign error: no provisioning profile at path '/Users/iloop/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/C6EBB162-0B68-4816-8EFC-79C0643BEE54.mobileprovision'

I'm going to be honest, I try not to mess AT ALL with the Provisioning Profiles, because as most things for developing for the big apple, you get screwed, and there is NEVER an easy way out.

I litteraly have NO IDEA what to do, other than wipe out the iPad mini, the Mac mini, and everything to see if it just happens to work, and even then I don't think it will.

When I connect the useless iPhone 4S it compiles and builds all fine, but with the iPad, noooo... I just want to stab a fork to my eye.

Comment: I take the last part back, now I cannot compile even on my iPhone... please just kill me

Comment: You have to add your iPad's identifier to your provisioning profile device list

Comment: Then u have to add provisioning profile to mac keychain.And in ur project settings set this profile as provisioning profile and set ur code signing authority also.

Comment: Now that I see it, the provisioning profile to debug now is just an UUID... I have no idea why it is not recognizing it now

Comment: Now i see what's the problem, this thing is not recognizing the appropriate provisioning profile. It doesn't even show on the list of my account while on XCode.

Comment: I'm done, I just asked for authorization, and created a new provisioning profile.

Comment: Now I get "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"... The device is on the device list, I'm fetching the provisioning profiles for that account... orz

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the certification had been revoked, and the new provisioning profile was using a different certification, that also automatically changed ID.

My team wasted all the day trying to figure out the problem, and then changing all the ID's and certifications. Now that's what I call the apple experience.